# SQL - Two Foreign Keys with different ON DELETE behaviour

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following SQL Statement:

```
CREATE TABLE `product_tag` (
          `product_id` BINARY(16) NOT NULL,
          `product_version_id` BINARY(16) NOT NULL,
          `tag_id` BINARY(16) NOT NULL,
          PRIMARY KEY (`product_id`, `product_version_id`, `tag_id`),
          CONSTRAINT `fk.product_tag.product_id` FOREIGN KEY (`product_id`)
            REFERENCES `product` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
          CONSTRAINT `fk.product_tag.product_version_id` FOREIGN KEY (`product_version_id`)
            REFERENCES `product` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
          CONSTRAINT `fk.product_tag.tag_id` FOREIGN KEY (`tag_id`)
            REFERENCES `tag` (`id`)
        ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

`product_id` aswell as `version_id`  need to be foreign keys. However, I want a different `ON DELETE` behaviour for each foreign key.

I need `ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE` for `product_id` and `ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE` for `product_version_id`.

How does the Statement need to look like?

Comment: ON DELETE/UPDATE actions of two FKs are not dependent. Specify the action which you need for each FK.

Comment: Please have a look at my edited statement. This should be technically correct, right? Now I am getting a `Cannot add foreign key constraint `...

Comment: There are a number of causes of that error. There are many previous questions about it that list the reasons. Search for the error message and you'll find them.

Comment: *Now I am getting a Cannot add foreign key constraint ...* You must read the whole error message, not first 5 words of it. The rest of the error message must be "Column 'product_version_id' cannot be NOT NULL: needed in a foreign key constraint 'fk.product_tag.product_version_id' SET NULL". It seems the error in your logic is obvious. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=393a5021c0dbc6f6aeaab5f40971ff64

Comment: You can't use `ON DELETE SET NULL` if the column is declared `NOT NULL`.

Comment: Thank you very much, haven't thought about that!